# Как вывести в файл float с запятой?

Tags: python, csv

Подскажите, как вывести в `csv` файл строку, в которой содержатся числа `float`, но не с точкой а с запятой? Видел что можно прописать

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')
```

Но не помогло

---

Мне нужно вывести данные вида

```
1,99; 2,33
```

Я получаю

```
"1,99"; "2,33" или 1.99; 2.33
```

Comment: `'{:n}'.format(число)`

Comment: @andreymal но он таким образом выводит `string`, а не `float` же

Comment: Так csv-файл не может содержать ничего кроме строк. Непонятно в чём проблема

Comment: @andreymal проблема в том что вашим способом выводятся: `"1,99"; "2,33"` - с ковычками

Comment: Чем вы пишете `csv` файл? От этого надо плясать.

Comment: Обычно у библиотек есть параметр записи в `csv` файл, например у `Pandas` это будет `decimal=','`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,"ru_RU")

value = 3.1415

print(locale.str(value))
```

Answer (score 3):

Локализация вывода чисел управляется так:

```
import locale

s =  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'ru_RU')

x=3.14
formatted = locale.format_string("%.2f", x)
print(formatted)
```

Подробно можно посмотреть тут:

https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/6.3.php

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том что `delimiter` стоял также `,` (запятая), а необходимо выбрать любой другой. Итого решением стало

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')
```